# Export map to PDF using Esri JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, pdf, geospatial-pdf

I've searched a lot and tried many ways to export a web map to PDF.
I need to export a web map and all active layers.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This will be much easier with Server 10.1 if you want to wait that out. Otherwise, the best way I've found is to use a server-side arcpy geoprocessor to do the exporting.

Comment: I just saw a blog on the new 3.0 api today.  I don't see this feature asked for, but you can run server side processes. Which might be jus tthe ticket for you.   http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/06/13/arcgis-api-for-javascript-version-3-0-released-2/

Answer (score 1):

This **[blog posting](http://giscollective.org/export-to-pdf-using-arcgis-javascript-api/)** from the GIS Collective seems to point the way to a **[sample solution](http://stlouis.esri.com/apps/exportmap/)** from Esri in St Louis:

> This Sample demonstrates the ability to use arcpy.mapping to  export
>   high quality PDF's from ESRI web API's using a GP service.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a hot issue for arcGis developers. 
The need for a map printing and exporting ability is discussed  in  [this forum](http://esri.force.com/ideaView?id=087300000008D0ZAAU&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DArcGIS%2BServer%26sort%3Dtop), where it is announced from the Esri experts that

> Thanks all the great feedback and comments.  ArcGIS for Server at version 10.1 now includes print tools.  The PrintingTool is a geoprocessing service that you can deploy along with templates to achieve high quality web map printing.  ArcGIS Web APIs will be able to communicate with this service to achieve printing via the web in a variety of popular formats such as JPG, PNG and PDF.   Here are more links for further reading.

Printing in Web Applications
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004w5000000

Using Your Own Layouts for Printing
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_your_own_lay

For more advanced printing and exporting you could also look at the [advanced printing topic.](http://esri.force.com/ideaView?id=087300000008D0ZAAU&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DArcGIS%2BServer%26sort%3Dtop)